# How to track application state per user

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee

I want to create a state machine to track the user operations in a JavaEE Web Application. The idea is generates states after the user has executed any action on the JSF backing beans. Each new state will be added into a list on the user context and after a while an asynchronous process will persist them into the database. I want to analyse the usability of the application; basically how the user interact with it, what the user likes and what doesn't like. I'll get metrics and improve the most used features. I have researched about that, but I couldn't find any framework or a library that does that for me. Have you got any suggestions?

**State.java** 
long id 
long userId
String state
Date dateTime
String className
String method
String componentId

I'm thinking in some kind of annotation and a parser, but anyway I didn't find the right answer for this requirement.

Comment: I would not try to track user actions on the base of classes and methods, but rather use cases - so functional instead of technical. Reason being that classes and methods may change due to refactoring, but use cases usually stay. And then you may just log the user interaction per use case in the database and have a little admin view for monitoring, I guess you won't need a framework for that.

Comment: Sorry but there is many companies creating their own state machines to track what the user does. It's a really powerful tool for app analysis, also is a good practise in case the app gets an expected state, so you can know with what user and where, plus the logs files. It's a different concept that logging stuff.

Answer (score 0):

A state machine is usually a predefined model, not a result of some computation, or user actions.

We, for example, have implemented a state machine to *force specific workflows upon the user*. The application can be in one state only (from the user's point of view) and the current state governs what activities are allowed next. The activity, in addition to performing actual work, always have a predefined state as endpoint.

What you are looking for, looks like a kind of [user browsing graph](http://wsdm2009.org/liu_2009_user_browsing_graph.pdf).
[Here](http://wadam.dis.uniroma1.it/pubs/early-adopter-graph.pdf) you can also find an example of statistics on user behavior.